# Autosize Forge text markup box size based on contents

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk

I have added some text markup using the following code:

```
const text = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.CreateText(
                editor,
                data.id
                textPosition,
                { x: 1, y: 0.5 }, //Size of the label
                data.name,
                textStyleObject,
            );
```

This looks like this when rendered:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically calculate the width of the label based on the content and reduce it accordingly so that it looks something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing the size of the label and check if it aligns automatically to the content size.

Comment: When I pass null in for the size, nothing gets added at all

Comment: Hi Richard, sorry I missed your comment, is your issue resolved.